# Grabbing elementID

Tags: javascript

I am creating a table with td ids as follows(id=concatenate(row,column)):

```
function createTable() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<table border="1" id="mytable"></table>';
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML += '<table border="1"><tr id="row' + i + '"></tr></table>';
    for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      document.getElementById("row" + i).innerHTML += '<td id=' + i + k + '></td>';
    }
  }
}
```

Then I want to change the background color of each cell depending on whether its value is >5 or below. This is the onclick function I call for each cell:

```
function clickable() {
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
  if (table != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
      table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { colorChange(i, j); };
    }
  }
}
function colorChange(i, j) {
  if (document.getElementById("" + i + j).innerHTML > 5) {
    document.getElementById("" + i + j).style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

but the debugger catches a typeError for trying to access a property of null in the first line of colorChange, which means my method of getting the elementID is wrong. What's the correct way to get the element ID?

Comment: You dont need `clickable` function you can just add onClick directly `document.getElementById("row" + i).innerHTML += '<td id=' + i + k + ' onclick="colorChange(i,j)"></td>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using vars for loop variables you always have i=4 and j=4 on click. Just replace those with let:

```js
function clickable() {
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
  if (table != null) {
    for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
      table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { colorChange(i, j); };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any of the `i` and `j` business. Just select the cell elements directly and loop through them to add an event listener, using `querySelectorAll`, as per the demo below.

N.B. You mentioned that you want to *"change the background color of each cell depending on whether its value is >5 or below"* ...but how are you defining the "value"? It's isn't clear. In the colorChange function, you try to test the value using the cell's "innerHTML", but your cells don't have any content anyway, so it would never work.

Therefore, for the purposes of the demo, I've assumed you intended to populate the cells with the values of `i` and `k`, and then interpret those as a single number when you do the test in colorChange.

Also `<table border="1">` needed to be removed. You can't have a table directly within another table. And it's not necessary, anyway.

```js
function createTable() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<table border="1" id="mytable"></table>';
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML += '<tr id="row' + i + '"></tr></table>';
    for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      document.getElementById("row" + i).innerHTML += '<td id=' + i + k + '>' + i + k + '</td>';
    }
  }
}

function clickable() {
  var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#mytable td");
  cells.forEach(function(cell) {
    cell.addEventListener("click", colorChange);
  });
}

function colorChange() {
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
  if (this.innerHTML > 5) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}

createTable();
clickable();
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll for documentation.

Comment: The first row is not clickable in the demo. But this looks simpler, thanks for the reference. I populate the cells later but I saw no reason to include the fill function in the question.

Comment: @UserX No, the first row _is_ clickable, but it doesn't do anything visible when clicked, because its "value" is less than 5 - as per (my best guess at) your requirements. If you add a `console.log` command into the colorChange function you'd see it logs every time, no matter which cell is clicked. I updated the answer with that, so you can see when you run the demo.

Comment: Oh yeah the breakpoint is 5 here, got confused with my original problem that I edited to make the question simpler.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing an opening curly bracket on the "j" loop of clickable

```
for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
```

I also changed colorChange() to work with the event target:

```js
function createTable() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<table border="1" id="mytable"></table>';
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML += '<table border="1"><tr id="row' + i + '"></tr></table>';
    for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      document.getElementById("row" + i).innerHTML += "<td id=" + i + k + ">" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + "</td>";
    }
  }
}

function clickable() {
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
  if (table != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
        table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function(event) {
          colorChange(event);
        };
      }
    }
  }
}

function colorChange(event) {
  const cell = event.target;
  if (cell.innerHTML > 5) {
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createTable();clickable()">run</button>
```

Comment: No, the brackets are not the problem - one-line code blocks are allowed without the brackets. If there was a missing bracket there would be a syntax error there, but there isn't. The change to the colorChange function is the bit which is making it work.